# Modification on a corollary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

[image]

captured from Chapter11 of Carothers' Real Analysis, 1ed and X denotes a compact metric space. Can I claim that uniformly convergent is not necessary here cos every convergent sequence in C(X) is uniformly convergent?

Comment: Convergence in $C(X)$ is the same as uniform convergence.

Comment: @TooOldForMath:^_^ Thanks

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, so this can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence in $C(X)$ is the same as uniform convergence.